# VS Code remote ssh: how to allow processes to keep running to completion after disconnect?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, openssh

I am using VS Code to do remote Python development on an Ubuntu Server via ssh.  VS Code handles the ssh connection.  I launch processes from the IDE.  If there is a disconnect even very briefly, the processes are killed.

Is there a way to stop that from happening?  I expected that there would be a setting in VS Code because there is a VS Code server that gets installed on the remote machine but have found nothing.

Note:  I tried the recommended procedure by Moreno [here](https://medium.com/@joaomoreno/persistent-terminal-sessions-in-vs-code-8fc469ed6b41) where he uses 'tmux' however it was not successful in Linux unless you use the mod that Faria presents in the comments section

Update:  It is possible to 'break' the solution proposed by Moreno.  After a lengthy disconnect VS Code started returning 'The terminal process /home/.../code-shell failed to launch (exit code: 1)'. Following the recommended trouble-shooting did not correct the problem.  Ended up restarting VS Code which is a suboptimal solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted I am working VS Code in a remote Ubuntu environment that I ssh in to.  If you are doing so follow the steps that are outlined by Moreno (see link in question) BUT because I am working in a Linux environment I had to adjust some items in the script.  The adjustments are:

1. make sure you set file permissions on 'code-shell' so that execution
   is possible.  So in my case at the CLI I did `chmod a+x code-shell` allowed execution by anyone but you can make it
   whatever you're comfortable with;
2. make the shebang line in your script use `/usr/bin/env bash`
   which will choose the first permissible shell your environment will
   allow.  Using `/bin/bash` did not work for me.
3. a slight change to the naming portion of the script.  I made it
   'vscode' followed by the first 3 characters of md5 sum.  That makes
   new terminals distinguishable.

The final script which works for me is:
[image]

So the whole process is: set up for ssh remote in VS Code -> adjust VS Code settings in workspace to run modified terminal (code-shell) -> create code-shell script with required permissions.  If you get a disconnect running processes will continue uninterrupted.